# Selenium IDE replace string within stored variable

Tags: javascript, string, selenium, replace, selenium-ide

I'm trying to replace " characters within text stored within a Selenium IDE test.

As an example I'm doing

```
<tr>
<td>storeText</td>
<td>id=request-header</td>
<td>variable1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>echo</td>
<td>javascript{'hi'.replace('i','a')}</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>echo</td>
<td>javascript{$variable1.replace('G','a')}</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

The first echo outputs 'ha' but the second results in an error.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In javascript execution context you have to use the **storedVars** array to access stored variables:

```
<tr>
  <td>echo</td>
  <td>javascript{storedVars.variable1.replace('G','a')}</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```